# Use rename to minus 199 from a batch of files

Tags: bash, perl, rename, jpeg, batch-rename

I have a folder of files named ts200.jpg, ts201.jpg, and so on. I need a program or command that will see the number, and minus 199 from the number, so ts200.jpg would become ts1.jpg, and so on.

I installed PERL rename, but I cannot comprehend the docs.

Any answers appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just use a perl one-liner directly, not its rename utility:

```bash
$ ls *.jpg
ts200.jpg ts201.jpg
$ perl -e 'rename $_, $_ =~ s/\d+/$&-199/er for @ARGV' *.jpg
$ ls *.jpg
ts1.jpg ts2.jpg
```

Comment: Just to double check, if I had more files up to like, ts600.jpg, would it still work?

Comment: @WiiCoder4444 Yeah.

Comment: Re "*if I had more files up to like, ts600.jpg, would it still work?*", 1) `*.jpg` might produce a command line that's too long if you have hundreds of files. This could be resolved using `find ... -exec perl -e'...' {} +`. 2) **It could result in data loss.** Imagine if ts600 gets renamed to ts401 before ts401 gets renamed? This can be fixed by moving them to a new directory by using `rename $_, "new/" . s/\d+/$&-199/er`.

Comment: Thanks! Next time i do a timelapse ill use that command